# I am trying to make the password encrypted when a user registers but I'm not sure how to do it?

Tags: java, encryption, passwords

This is my code below

```
package javaapplication1;
/*
This is the registration class
This is the class that has the code to
Add a new employee
This is by entering such information as their
Username
Password Business Name
Type of Business
Email
Contact Number
Address
Employee Status
*/

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Registration extends javax.swing.JFrame {
public static Random rand = new Random((new Date()).getTime());
  Statement stmt;
public Registration() {
    initComponents();
}
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    EnterButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    ClearButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    UserNameLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    ContactNumberLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    AddressLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    EmailLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    UsernameTextField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    BusinessNameTextField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    RegistrationLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    PasswordLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    BusinessNameLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    TypeOfBusinessLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    EmailTextField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    ContactNumberTextField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    AddressTextField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    PasswordTextField = new javax.swing.JPasswordField();
    BusinessTypeComboBox = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
    EmployedLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    YesRadioButton = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
    NoRadioButton = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(93, 432));

    EnterButton.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 16)); // NOI18N
    EnterButton.setText("Enter");
    EnterButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            EnterButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    ClearButton.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 16)); // NOI18N
    ClearButton.setText("Clear");
    ClearButton.setToolTipText("");
    ClearButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            ClearButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    UserNameLabel.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
    UserNameLabel.setLabelFor(UsernameTextField);
    UserNameLabel.setText("UserName");

    ContactNumberLabel.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
    ContactNumberLabel.setText("Contact Number");

    AddressLabel.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
    AddressLabel.setLabelFor(BusinessNameTextField);
    AddressLabel.setText("Address");
    AddressLabel.setToolTipText("");

    EmailLabel.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
    EmailLabel.setText("Email");

    UsernameTextField.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            UsernameTextFieldActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    BusinessNameTextField.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            BusinessNameTextFieldActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    RegistrationLabel.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 24)); // NOI18N
    RegistrationLabel.setText("Employee Registration");
    RegistrationLabel.setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
    RegistrationLabel.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(100, 25));

    PasswordLabel.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
    PasswordLabel.setText("Password");

    BusinessNameLabel.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
    BusinessNameLabel.setText("Business Name");

    TypeOfBusinessLabel.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
    TypeOfBusinessLabel.setText("Type of Business");

    EmailTextField.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            EmailTextFieldActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    ContactNumberTextField.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            ContactNumberTextFieldActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    AddressTextField.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            AddressTextFieldActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    BusinessTypeComboBox.setEditable(true);
    BusinessTypeComboBox.setMaximumRowCount(30);
    BusinessTypeComboBox.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "", "Laundromat", "Computer Shop" }));
    BusinessTypeComboBox.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(95, 20));
    BusinessTypeComboBox.setName(""); // NOI18N
    BusinessTypeComboBox.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(900, 900));
    BusinessTypeComboBox.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            BusinessTypeComboBoxActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    EmployedLabel.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
    EmployedLabel.setText("Employed");

    YesRadioButton.setText("Yes");
    YesRadioButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            YesRadioButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    NoRadioButton.setText("No");
    NoRadioButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            NoRadioButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(278, 278, 278)
                    .addComponent(RegistrationLabel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(189, 189, 189)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(BusinessNameLabel)
                        .addComponent(PasswordLabel)
                        .addComponent(UserNameLabel)
                        .addComponent(TypeOfBusinessLabel)
                        .addComponent(EmailLabel)
                        .addComponent(ContactNumberLabel)
                        .addComponent(AddressLabel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 69, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(EmployedLabel))
                    .addGap(38, 38, 38)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(BusinessTypeComboBox, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 218, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(ContactNumberTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 218, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(EmailTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 218, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(2, 2, 2)
                            .addComponent(BusinessNameTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 218, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addComponent(PasswordTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 218, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(UsernameTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 218, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(AddressTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 218, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(YesRadioButton)
                            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                            .addComponent(NoRadioButton))))
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(ClearButton)
                        .addComponent(EnterButton))
                    .addGap(177, 177, 177)))
            .addGap(0, 210, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(33, 33, 33)
            .addComponent(RegistrationLabel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(UsernameTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                    .addComponent(PasswordTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(16, 16, 16)
                    .addComponent(BusinessNameTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                    .addComponent(BusinessTypeComboBox, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 23, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(UserNameLabel)
                    .addGap(16, 16, 16)
                    .addComponent(PasswordLabel)
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addComponent(BusinessNameLabel)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(TypeOfBusinessLabel)))
            .addGap(6, 6, 6)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(EmailTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 22, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(EmailLabel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 29, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(ContactNumberTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(ContactNumberLabel))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(AddressTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(AddressLabel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 30, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(13, 13, 13)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(EmployedLabel)
                .addComponent(YesRadioButton)
                .addComponent(NoRadioButton))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(EnterButton)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(ClearButton)
            .addContainerGap(79, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

public static String encrypt(String passwordToHash){
     String generatedPassword = null;
    try {
        // Create MessageDigest instance for MD5
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        //Add password bytes to digest
        md.update(passwordToHash.getBytes());
        //Get the hash's bytes 
        byte[] bytes = md.digest();
        //This bytes[] has bytes in decimal format;
        //Convert it to hexadecimal format
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i=0; i< bytes.length ;i++)
        {
            sb.append(Integer.toString((bytes[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
        }
        //Get complete hashed password in hex format
        generatedPassword = sb.toString();
    } 
    catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return generatedPassword;
}


private void UsernameTextFieldActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                  
    // This is the text field for the username
}                                                 

private void BusinessNameTextFieldActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                      
    // This is the text field for the type of business
}                                                     

private void EnterButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    /* This is the enter button.
       When this is pressed the customers details are entered in the database
   */

    String url = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Customers";
    String username = "username";
    String password = "password";

    String encString = encrypt(PasswordTextField.getText());
    try {
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
         if (conn !=null){
            System.out.println("Connected");
            String sql = "INSERT INTO Registration (username, Password, businessName, typeofBusiness, email, contactnumber, address, Employed) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
            PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            statement.setString(1, UsernameTextField.getText());
            statement.setString(2, encString = (PasswordTextField.getText()));  
            statement.setString(3, BusinessNameTextField.getText());
            statement.setString(4, BusinessTypeComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString());
            statement.setString(5, EmailTextField.getText());
            statement.setString(6, ContactNumberTextField.getText());
            statement.setString(7, AddressTextField.getText());
            statement.setString(8, EmployStatus);


            int rowsInserted = statement.executeUpdate();
            if (rowsInserted > 0) {
                final JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
                dialog.setAlwaysOnTop(true);    
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(dialog, "A new user has been added successfully");
            }
        }

} catch (SQLException ex){
                final JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
                dialog.setAlwaysOnTop(true);    
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(dialog, "ERROR!");
    }
}                                           

private void ClearButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
/*This is the Clear button
When it is pressed it will clear all the text fields
*/
UsernameTextField.setText("");
PasswordTextField.setText("");
BusinessNameTextField.setText("");
EmailTextField.setText("");
ContactNumberTextField.setText("");
AddressTextField.setText("");
}                                           

private void EmailTextFieldActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
    // This is the email
}                                              

private void ContactNumberTextFieldActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                       
    // This is the customers contact number 
}                                                      

private void AddressTextFieldActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 
    // This is the customers address
}                                                

private void BusinessTypeComboBoxActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                     
    /* This the drop down list for the type of business
       The user can choose a company already on the lisr or they can enter a new company
    */
}                                                    

private void YesRadioButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
    // This is the yes radio button for if the employee is still employed
    EmployStatus = "Yes";
}                                              

private void NoRadioButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    // This is the no radio button for if the employee is still employed
    EmployStatus = "No";
}                                             
public static void main(String args[]) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Registration().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JLabel AddressLabel;
private javax.swing.JTextField AddressTextField;
private javax.swing.JLabel BusinessNameLabel;
private javax.swing.JTextField BusinessNameTextField;
private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> BusinessTypeComboBox;
private javax.swing.JButton ClearButton;
private javax.swing.JLabel ContactNumberLabel;
private javax.swing.JTextField ContactNumberTextField;
private javax.swing.JLabel EmailLabel;
private javax.swing.JTextField EmailTextField;
private javax.swing.JLabel EmployedLabel;
private javax.swing.JButton EnterButton;
private javax.swing.JRadioButton NoRadioButton;
private javax.swing.JLabel PasswordLabel;
private javax.swing.JPasswordField PasswordTextField;
private javax.swing.JLabel RegistrationLabel;
private javax.swing.JLabel TypeOfBusinessLabel;
private javax.swing.JLabel UserNameLabel;
private javax.swing.JTextField UsernameTextField;
private javax.swing.JRadioButton YesRadioButton;
// End of variables declaration                   
private String EmployStatus;
 }
```

This will encrypt the password

```
      public static String encrypt(String passwordToHash){
     String generatedPassword = null;
    try {
        // Create MessageDigest instance for MD5
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        //Add password bytes to digest
        md.update(passwordToHash.getBytes());
        //Get the hash's bytes 
        byte[] bytes = md.digest();
        //This bytes[] has bytes in decimal format;
        //Convert it to hexadecimal format
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i=0; i< bytes.length ;i++)
        {
            sb.append(Integer.toString((bytes[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
        }
        //Get complete hashed password in hex format
        generatedPassword = sb.toString();
    } 
    catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return generatedPassword;
}
```

But I don't know how to apply this to the password that the user enters so that when the password is entered into the database here

```
                 String sql = "INSERT INTO Registration (username, Password, businessName, typeofBusiness, email, contactnumber, address, Employed) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
            PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            statement.setString(1, UsernameTextField.getText());
            statement.setString(2, encString = (PasswordTextField.getText()));  
            statement.setString(3, BusinessNameTextField.getText());
            statement.setString(4, BusinessTypeComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString());
            statement.setString(5, EmailTextField.getText());
            statement.setString(6, ContactNumberTextField.getText());
            statement.setString(7, AddressTextField.getText());
            statement.setString(8, EmployStatus);


            int rowsInserted = statement.executeUpdate();
            if (rowsInserted > 0) {
                final JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
                dialog.setAlwaysOnTop(true);    
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(dialog, "A new user has been added successfully");
            }
        }
```

The password stored would be the encrypted password

Comment: I found out the problem

my password field was too short

Answer (score 1):

Instead use an itererated HMAC, functions that do this include `PBKDF2`, `password_hash`, `bcrypt`, etc.

Notes:

Do not use `Random` with the time as a seed, to get a seed, use the cryptographic CPRNG: java.security.SecureRandom, it does not need to be seeded.

Do not use MD5 (attackers love it).

Hasing is not encryption, it is a one-way function, encryption is a two-way (it can be decrypted).

Comment: MD5 hashes, at password input lengths, are easily reversible, so is that still 1-way?

Comment: No they are not "easily reversible", they are still one-way functions. Rainbow tables can be used against MD5 because of the short output length cane is thwarted by the use of a random salt. The current main attack vector is brute force using tables of known passwords ordered by occurrence combined with the fast execution of cryptographic functions on todays hardware. Thus there is a real need to use an iterated HMAC with a minimum execution time of around 100ms. This takes us back to `PBKDF2`, `password_hash`, `bcrypt` and similar functions.

Comment: Times from my 2012 laptop:  MD5: 0.355 us, SHA-256: 0.473 us, HMAC SHA-256: 1.36 us. Even salting (SHA-256 vs HMAC SHA-256) only minimaly shows down the hash. What the salt does is keeps finding one password from a hash  from exposing all other passwords with the same hash.

Answer (score 0):

```
statement.setString(2, encrypt(PasswordTextField.getText()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you call `Registration.encrypt(PasswordTextField.getText())` when setting the strings?

Also, nitpick: the password is (and should be) being hashed, not encrypted. Encryption implies it can be decrypted.